# How to efficiently find last preceding row with nonzero value in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Introduction**

I am trying to find the optimal way how to find the last preceding row with nonzero value in a given column and return a value of different column on that row. I want to do it in R data.table and i am looking for maximum efficiency of that operation.

**Example**

let's have a data table like so:

```
set.seed(123)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=6),
                y=rep(1:6, 3),
                z = rbinom(18, 1, 0.3))
```

That gives us the following data table:

```
    x y z
 1: b 1 0
 2: b 2 1
 3: b 3 0
 4: b 4 1
 5: b 5 1
 6: b 6 0
 7: a 1 0
 8: a 2 1
 9: a 3 0
10: a 4 0
11: a 5 1
12: a 6 0
13: c 1 0
14: c 2 0
15: c 3 0
16: c 4 1
17: c 5 0
18: c 6 0
```

Now, the table is for each value in column x ordered by the column y. For each group given by the values in column `x`, I would like to create a column which would give me for each row the value of `y` from the row with last nonzero value of `z`.

Right now I am using lapply for each y and grouping by x which gives the desired result:

```
DT[, list(y,
          z, 
          output = lapply(y, function(x) max(y[z != 0 & y <= x]))
          ), 
   by = 'x']
```

**The question**

Can i make my code from the example more efficient?

Comment: I've tested the rolling join and non-equi join suggested bellow and rolling join turned out to be faster in my scenario. Can't say if it was just due to the setup or if it will be the case generally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option using rolling join:

```
DT[, output:= DT[z==1][.SD, on=.(x, y), roll=Inf, x.y]]
```

output:

```
    x y z output
 1: b 1 0     NA
 2: b 2 1      2
 3: b 3 0      2
 4: b 4 1      4
 5: b 5 1      5
 6: b 6 0      5
 7: a 1 0     NA
 8: a 2 1      2
 9: a 3 0      2
10: a 4 0      2
11: a 5 1      5
12: a 6 0      5
13: c 1 0     NA
14: c 2 0     NA
15: c 3 0     NA
16: c 4 1      4
17: c 5 0      4
18: c 6 0      4
```

Answer (score 5):

You might try using `nafill`:

```
# create a dummy column that is only populated for nonzero z (and hence NA elsewhere)
DT[z != 0, y_copy := y]
# nafill on this column using LOCF strategy by group:
DT[ , ans := nafill(y_copy, type = 'locf'), by = x][]
#     x y z y_copy ans
#  1: b 1 0     NA  NA
#  2: b 2 1      2   2
#  3: b 3 0     NA   2
#  4: b 4 1      4   4
#  5: b 5 1      5   5
#  6: b 6 0     NA   5
#  7: a 1 0     NA  NA
#  8: a 2 1      2   2
#  9: a 3 0     NA   2
# 10: a 4 0     NA   2
# 11: a 5 1      5   5
# 12: a 6 0     NA   5
# 13: c 1 0     NA  NA
# 14: c 2 0     NA  NA
# 15: c 3 0     NA  NA
# 16: c 4 1      4   4
# 17: c 5 0     NA   4
# 18: c 6 0     NA   4
```

For now, `nafill` is a development only feature (`data.table` 1.12.3+) but 1.12.4 should be on CRAN in the next week or two. For the moment, you can install this with `install.packages('data.table', type = 'source', repos = 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table')`

If you don't want to create `y_copy`, you could do this inline with `is.na<-`:

```
DT[ , ans := nafill(`is.na<-`(y, z == 0), type = 'locf'), by = x]
```

This will be inefficient because `z==0` is calculated repeatedly by group (instead of as a single vector); you could do this in the first step then:

```
DT[ , z_zero := z == 0]
```

But this means another dummy column (with less storage than `y_copy` if `y` is `numeric`, `character`, or `complex`)

Comment: Or use gitlab repo url to install from binaries so Rtools will not be needed to install on windows

Answer (score 3):

An option with non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
DT[DT[z!=0, .(y1 = y, x)], output := y1, on = .(x, y <= y1), 
         mult = 'last'][, output := na.locf0(output), x]
DT
#    x y z output
# 1: b 1 0     NA
# 2: b 2 1      2
# 3: b 3 0      2
# 4: b 4 1      4
# 5: b 5 1      5
# 6: b 6 0      5
# 7: a 1 0     NA
# 8: a 2 1      2
# 9: a 3 0      2
#10: a 4 0      2
#11: a 5 1      5
#12: a 6 0      5
#13: c 1 0     NA
#14: c 2 0     NA
#15: c 3 0     NA
#16: c 4 1      4
#17: c 5 0      4
#18: c 6 0      4
```